# Reformulate an SDP to something simpler

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to solve the following problem where $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ and $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Also, $Z \succ 0$ and $X \succeq 0$
\begin{equation}
\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}} y^\top(Z + X)^{-1} y
\end{equation}

It can be reformulated as an SDP
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{t, X \succeq 0}&\ t \\
\text{st:}& \left[\begin{array}{cc}
t & y^\top \\
y & X + Z
\end{array}\right] \succeq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Is it possible to solve this problem without formulating it as an SDP ? Either algorithmically or something simpler than SDP.

Comment: You need some constraint like $X \succeq 0$ or $Z+X \succeq 0$ as otherwise the problem is unbounded below. The original objective is convex so you can use any algorithm for constrained convex optimization, but if you are looking for an accurate solution, I doubt you can do better than an interior point method for SDP.

Comment: @LinAlg I added a psd constraint on $X$